# would `as` enable polymorphism? would pass a inherited class to a method which takes a base class enable polymorphism?

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, as-operator

Fist of all, I will use `virtual` and `override`

for example, base class A has method `A.do()`, inherited class B has `B.do()` which overrides A's.

if I call `(B as A).do()`, which `do()` would it execute?

or, if there is a method `void mymethod(A a) {a.do()}`, now I call it by `B b; mymethod(b)`, would it execute `b.do()`?

Comment: Let me answer your question with another question: which one was called when you tested this code? And by the way the `as` operator works on object instances, not on types as in your example.

Comment: Seems that you want to **dis** able polymorphism

Comment: this is not overriding but hiding. You get a warning from the compiler exactly for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most top override method always will be called, i.e. `b.Do()` or `(b as A).Do()` or `((A)b).Do()` will call `B.Do()`.

I don't know a way how to call a base method from child class if child class overrides it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Do() { Console.Write("a"); }
    public void Do2() { Console.Write("a2"); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Do() { Console.Write("b"); }
    public new void Do2() { Console.Write("b2"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        A a = b;
        b.Do();               //b
        ( b as A ).Do();      //b
        a.Do();               //b
        ( (A)b ).Do();        //b

        ( b as A ).Do2();     //a2
        ( (A)b ).Do2();       //a2
        ( b ).Do2();          //b2
    }
}
```

Output:

```
b b b b
a2 a2 b2
```

Comment: Actaully it will call `B.Do()` as far as `B : A`

Comment: You sure about that? When you suggest someone running the code maybe you should run it first.

Comment: @Nahum, abatishchev is correct. The dynamic dispatch works no matter how is the reference you reached it through declared (-1).

Comment: There is nothing to be embarrassed of. The important thing is that you now actually tested the code and posted a correct answer. That's what brings value to the community. I have replaced my downvote with an upvote and hope others would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on whether the do() method was declared virtual or not.  If it is not virtual then A.do() is called.  If it is virtual then B.do() is called.  It is the *virtual* keyword that enables polymorphism and allows calling a method independent of the type of the reference.

There is no mechanism in C# that allows directly calling a virtual A.do() method from a B object reference.  The only exception is using base.do() inside an instance method of class B.

Comment: yes i will reedit so make it clear i go the proper way of polymophism.. virtual + override

Comment: If `A.Do()` is not virtual so `B.Do()` does not override it but hide (with the appropriate compiler warning) - then `B.Do()` anyway will be called, will it not?

Comment: @abat - no, A.Do() is called when the object reference is of type A, either explicitly or by casting.  Try it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A
{
    public A() { }
    public void Do() { Console.Write("A"); }

}

public class B : A
{
    public B() { }
    public void Do() { Console.Write("B");  }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Do(); //<-- outputs B
        (b as A).Do(); //<-- outputs A
      }
}
```

compiler warns for **hiding** *not overriding*:

> Warning 1 'ConsoleApplication5.B.Do()' hides inherited member
>   'ConsoleApplication5.A.Do()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was
>   intended. c:\Program.cs   18  21  ConsoleApplication5

that is since you are not overriding anything, but simply hiding the method from A.

**however**

```
public class A
{
    public A() { }
    public virtual void Do() { Console.Write("A"); }

}

public class B : A
{
    public B() { }
    public  override void Do() { Console.Write("B");  }
}
```

calls **B** twice, when method is overridden.

Comment: sry, i meant to use `virtual` and `override`